# SidekiqUniqueJobs::UnknownLock: No implementation for `lock: :all`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq

I have implemented sidekiq, In which a number of jobs been executed So I wanted to add uniqueness on `default queue`, to add uniqueness on jobs I have used [sidekiq-unique-jobs](https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs) gem.

I have followed the below steps:

**Gemfile**

```
gem 'sidekiq-unique-jobs'
```

And then execute:

```
bundle install
```

**Worker.rb**

```
Class Worker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options retry: 2, unique_across_queues: true, queue: 'default',lock: :until_executing

  def perform(args); 
   ....
   ....
  end
end
```

After adding the above configuration on my worker I am getting below error:

> SidekiqUniqueJobs::UnknownLock: No implementation for `lock: :all`

Any suggestion will be appreciated!

Comment: seems there is a config in your project, setting lock: :all

Comment: @PanKe Thanks for the quick reply, which configuration are you talking about?

Comment: is `lock: :until_executing` the only lock configure in your project? any other sidekiq_options?

Comment: @PanKe This is only one lock configuration on my project.

Comment: hmmm, from code base, there is a `:all` `lock_type` in your project. https://github.com/mhenrixon/sidekiq-unique-jobs/blob/63974568db7e29ad4a3328e48af3243983fccf4a/lib/sidekiq_unique_jobs/options_with_fallback.rb#L53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other `sidekiq_options` in your project which set the `lock: :all`. try to grep in your project files and remove it.